# First project in django

Tags: python, django

Please help me in star learning django. I try to understand why i got 404 error.

There is my main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/', include('account_app.urls')),
]
```

My account urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

```
from account_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

There is my view of accout

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from yes_no.models import account_class # added to model yes_no


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('./index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'a' : a,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

P.S. My index.html file is exist in folder where accout view and urls file

Thank you for the help.

Comment: it should be in templates folder in your app or project, check django documentation

Comment: what's a?! you must initialize a variable.

Comment: Your 404 is caused by that leading slash in the including URL pattern. However as others have pointed out, there are lots of other things wing, especially where you've placed the template and how you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need start to use [Class Based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/)? All things get more easy.

urls.py should be like this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from some_app.views import HomePageView(

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/', HomePageView(.as_view()),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   ]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = dict()
        context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return Homepage.render_to_response(self, context)
```

And we need full trace with error